# Changing color of text after it is typed out again effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this typing carousel effect I got from codepen for my website, however, I need help modifying it. Right now, all it does it cycle through a list of words and types them out.

The desired effect I would like is that the text color of each separate word that is typed out is different. The words:

- nerdy.
- simple.
- pure JS.
- pretty.
- fun!

would all be different colors when they are typed out. How can I accomplish this?

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/gschier/pen/jkivt?q=typing%20carousel&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false)

```js
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 2;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #222;
  color: #aaa
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5em;
}

h2 {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h1>This pen is
  <span class="txt-rotate" data-period="2000" data-rotate='[ "nerdy.", "simple.", "pure JS.", "pretty.", "fun!" ]'></span>
</h1>
<h2>A single &lt;span&gt; is all you need.</h2>
```

Comment: Do you want any fixed colours to apply or there can be any random colours each time they typed in ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay My apologies, I forgot to specify. I'd like each word to have its own color. So the first word could be red, the second one would be blue, then green, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by defining an array of colours:

```
var colours = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"]
```

and setting it each loop:

```
this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap" style="color: ' + colours[i] + '">'+this.txt+'</span>';
```

Forked example: https://codepen.io/mark_c/pen/WEavqy?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to add another data attribute such as data-colors, then use those to rotate as well as the text. Using a modulus function will allow you to wrap the colors around if there are less colors than text. So you could have 14 text entries, but only two colors, so the colors would alternate between the two colors.

I customized the codepen with a very quick implementation that you could use, but here is the basics of what I changed:

**HTML**

```
<span
 class="txt-rotate"
 data-period="2000"
 data-rotate='[ "nerdy.", "simple.", "pure JS.", "pretty.", "fun!" ]'
 data-colors='[ "red", "blue", "green" ]'></span>
```

**Javascript**:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    var colors = elements[i].getAttribute('data-colors');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), JSON.parse(colors), period);
    }
  }
```

... lots of unchanged code ...

```
TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];
  var thisColor = this.colors[this.loopNum % this.colors.length];

  ... other unchanged code ...

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap" style="color:'+thisColor+'">'+this.txt+'</span>';
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaxbQL

Comment: Oops, spent too much time faffing with formatting :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the updated javascript which will give your desired output.

```
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};
var colors = ['red','blue','green'];    // Array of colours
TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap" style="color:'+colors[i]+'">'+this.txt+'</span>';    // Changing colours depending on word's index with colors.

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

Comment: Why down vote? Its working as per requirement. I have checked with Codepen.